# How to interpolate or extrapolate to dates in the past? (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I have a real time data set from one source that runs from 2003-2018. I have another source that has data of only 1990. I want to combine the data and make a time series from 1990-2018.

Using pandas I concatenated the series, which looks like te output below:

```
dates                           
1990-01-01   8.8  11.4
1990-02-01   7.8  12.8
1990-03-01   5.6  18.6
.....
2003-01-01   10.3 11.6
2003-02-01   9.6  15.0
2003-03-01   7.5  21.7
```

With re-indexing, I created a new frame, with frequency of a month and Nans for the missing values and followed this by interpolation of the missing data.

```
start = dtm.datetime(1990,1,1)
end = dtm.datetime(2018,12,1)

frames = [df1,df2]
combined = pd.concat(frames)
rsam = pd.date_range(start,end, freq = 'MS')
combined = combined.reindex(rsam,axis = 0)
combined['NH'] = combined['NH'].interpolate(method = 'spline', order = 3)
combined['SH'] = combined['SH'].interpolate(method = 'spline', order = 3)
```

If have tried different methods & adding limit_area, limit_direction etc.

However the interpolation gives me a really strange output.

[Plot output after interpolation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T89d8.png)

This is to my opinion due to the fact that the interpolation uses the data of 1990 to interpolate forward. However the data from 2003-2008 is the explanatory data and the data of 1990 just used to interpolate (in stead of extrapolating). How could I  create a time series which uses 2003-2008 to interpolate the data till 1990 and not the other way around?

I tried to reverse all the data, but reindexing won't work when the dates are not in normal order. Is it possible to do with pandas?

Comment: Could you edit your question and show the code you're using to interpolate?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: You would like to fix missing data for the time from 1990 to 2003 (13 years of missing data)?

Comment: @yoskovia I edited my question

Comment: @mozart_kv467 Yes indeed, I need a time series of 1990 to 2018 to put in a model. However currently there is no data between 1990 and 2003. Therefore I need to interpolate/extrapolate it. The data has a clear seasonality in 2003-2008.